# ACF allow duplicate value in select field

Tags: wordpress, select, duplicates, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a WordPress project and using ACF (advance custom field) plugin.

I have to display multiple values in select field designed by ACF, the values are like:

```
01 : Richard
15 : mike
01 : sam
01 : josh
```

But somehow ACF replace my values (Duplicate values like `01 : Richard`) from the options list.

I want to display all values including duplicate values in select field.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Why do you need duplicate values?

Comment: Because I am calculating the total amount through values but displaying the text in Select field. It may be possible as two options have same values but will have different text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in that way. The reason this happens is that ACF stores the values as an array, like this

```
$field['choices'] = [
    01 => 'Richard',
    15 => 'mike',
    01 => 'sam',
    01 => 'josh',
    ];
```

so it's an error